# Issues with Chrome Mac and Flash

Tags: macos, google-chrome, flash

I have a simple 250k flash movie a page i'm developing. The flash movie causes scrolling, javascript animations, and overall performance to be slow.

**Here's the code**

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    data="/media/slider.swf"
    width="520" height="348">
    <param name="autoplay" value="true">
    <param name="movie" value="/media/slider.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high"/>
</object>
```

The page performs normally on every other browser and OS pare i've tried it on. I've heard that the Chromes flash player on mac causes crashing and performance isn't great, but i'm having trouble finding a fix.

Any one having any success with this?

**EDIT**
Here's a sample page I put up real quick with the error. If you resize your browser and have the blue block visible with and without the flash, then hover you should see the error.
http://dev.danielcgold.com/flash/

Comment: What's the framerate of slider.swf?

Comment: Can you show us a swf file, so we could try it ourselves?

Comment: @deadrunk i've updated my post with a sample link

Comment: I have tested your code and overall performance is not so bad, though scrolling is slow, indeed. :( Setting `wmode` param to `opaque` gives some improve, http://pastebin.com/FfQLjVbg, but also I suggest to decrease fps to 10 and review animaitons in your swf clip.

Comment: @deadrunk looks like adding a wmode param worked. Transparent and opaque both had the same results. Thanks! If you add your comment as a question I can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Ok, I did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and overall performance is not so bad, though scrolling is slow, indeed. :( Setting wmode param to opaque gives some improve, pastebin.com/FfQLjVbg, but also I suggest to decrease fps to 10 and review animaitons in your swf clip.